# Campaign member standard field access issue

Tags: soql, campaign-member

I am trying to get the Campaign members with some criteria from a Dot net system.

While I am trying to query the campaign members getting this following error.

> InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: INVALID_FIELD:
>   LastModifiedById, Date_Status__c, City, CompanyOrAccount, Country ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:690 No such column 'City' on entity
>   'CampaignMember'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure
>   to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: what API level is being used by the .Net client when querying?

Comment: Bulk API is used to retrieve the data.

Comment: Yes.  And what version of the bulk API?